# Detecting when an iframe is closing

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe

We are using Salesforce and have embedded iframes that show content from another application we have developed.  When the user is working on fields in our iframe and lose focus on them, the iframe script saves their input back to our system.  However, there can be instances where the user enters data in one of our fields, but never loses focus and then directs the outer salesforce shell to navigate to a different page.  This causes our field to never save because it never lost focus.

So for an iframe, is there some sort of unload event that we can attach to and detect if we need to save before the page refreshes with another salesforce view?

Comment: there's no reliably way to detect when a user navigates away from a page. things like window.onload are available in some browsers, but may not trigger properly.

Comment: Does the window.onbeforeunload event fire?

Comment: beforeunload event is fired but can be prevented by other script so you don't have clue whether window is really being closed or not at the end

Answer (score 3):

you can use following code in your custom app.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var confirmClose = 'Are you sure?';
    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (event) {
       event.returnValue = confirmClose;
    }
    // For Safari
    return confirmClose;
}
```

Comment: Kindly provide a **Use case example** showing your solution in action. How can someone implement your suggested solution?

Comment: this is just how to prevent unload.. but I agree that author can probably use this for saving fields values event it is not sure that some other script does not prevent unload so it must be OK to save values even in such case